# Failed resolving method subscribe on class com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.internal.zzs

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, nativescript

I get an error during the runtime of a nativescipt project:

```
    An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onConnected failed

Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method subscribe on class com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.internal.zzs
    com.tns.Runtime.resolveMethodOverload(Runtime.java:983)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1022)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:907)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:895)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:879)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:871)
```

Executing the following code:

```
var test = ...//GoogleApiClient
var SubscribeOptions = com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeOptions;
var Strategy = com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Strategy;
var MessageListener = com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessageListener.extend({
                onFound: function(message){
                    Log.d("MESSAGE", "Found message :) ");
                },
                onLost: function(message){
                    Log.d("MESSAGE", "Lost message :( ");
                }


        });
        var mMessageListener = new MessageListener();

        var options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
                .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
                .build();
        var mMessages = new com.google.android.gms.nearby.Nearby.Messages.subscribe(test, mMessageListener, options);
```

During the build process I get some executions, could they be the cause? If yes, how to solve it?

```
 Merged dex #50 (1 defs/1,3KiB)
Merged dex #51 (3445 defs/3916,6KiB)
Result is 3495 defs/4907,8KiB. Took 0,2s
:buildMetadata
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Skip com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz
        Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
 'assets/metadata/treeNodeStream.dat' NOT FOUND
 'assets/metadata/treeStringsStream.dat' NOT FOUND
 'assets/metadata/treeValueStream.dat' NOT FOUND
 'assets/metadata/treeNodeStream.dat'...
 'assets/metadata/treeStringsStream.dat'...
 'assets/metadata/treeValueStream.dat'...
:mergeF0DebugJniLibFolders
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForF0Debug
```

I am using GooglePlayServices 9.8.0

According to the Android reference this is the syntax.
It is working in Android Studio.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/Messages.html#subscribe(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeOptions)

Please help me :)

Comment: No hint? Anyone? :(